# Numpy: how to select full row based on some columns

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.array([[1.,2.,3.],
          [3.,4.,2.],
          [8.,1.,3.]])
b = [8.,1.]
c = a[np.isclose(a[:,0:2],b)]
print(c)
```

I want to select full rows in `a` based on only a few columns. My attempt is above.

It works if I include the last column too in that condition, but I don't care about the last column. How do I select rows with 3 columns, based on a condition on 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare with `np.isclose` using the sliced version of `a` and then look for all matches along each row, for which we can use `np.all` or `np.logical_and.reduce`. Finally, index into input array for the output.

Hence, two solutions -

```
a[np.isclose(a[:,:2],b).all(axis=1)]
a[np.logical_and.reduce( np.isclose(a[:,:2],b), axis=1)]
```